# How can we add dynamic html5 data attribute in django admin form

Tags: django, django-admin

I just want to ask how we can add additional dynamic html5 data attribute in each fiels in django admin forms.

For example

```
    <option value ="1" data-desc="desc1">hello1</option>
    <option value ="2" data-desc="desc2">hello2</option>
```

Thanks,

Kel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to subclass Django's ModelChoiceField and modify it's `render_options()` and `render_option()` methods to display the object's attributes you need. I guess you also need your own subclass of ModelChoiceIterator so that it not only spits out id/label tuples but all the data you need.

## Example

I just found an implementation of a custom SelectWidget in [OpenStack's dashboard](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/sourcecode/horizon/horizon.forms.fields.html#horizon.forms.fields.data_attrs):

```
class SelectWidget(widgets.Select):
    """
    Customizable select widget, that allows to render
    data-xxx attributes from choices.

    .. attribute:: data_attrs

        Specifies object properties to serialize as
        data-xxx attribute. If passed ('id', ),
        this will be rendered as:
        <option data-id="123">option_value</option>
        where 123 is the value of choice_value.id

    .. attribute:: transform

        A callable used to render the display value
        from the option object.
    """

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), data_attrs=(), transform=None):
        self.data_attrs = data_attrs
        self.transform = transform
        super(SelectWidget, self).__init__(attrs, choices)

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
        other_html = (option_value in selected_choices) and \
                         u' selected="selected"' or ''
        if not isinstance(option_label, (basestring, Promise)):
            for data_attr in self.data_attrs:
                data_value = html.conditional_escape(
                    force_unicode(getattr(option_label,
                                          data_attr, "")))
                other_html += ' data-%s="%s"' % (data_attr, data_value)

            if self.transform:
                option_label = self.transform(option_label)
        return u'<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>' % (
            html.escape(option_value), other_html,
            html.conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label)))
```

**EDIT**

As long as you provide choices like this, it should work:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'dummy':
        widget = SelectWidget(data_attrs=('bar',))
        choices = [(foo.id, foo) for foo in Foo.objects.all()]
        form_field = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=choices, widget=widget)
        return form_field
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me out of the box using Django 1.7 using a normal ModelChoiceField. I had to override the label_from_instance method, like this:

    `def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj`

Comment: This is to complicated for such simple task. Django has to do something about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`get_form()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method to tweak the form that is used by a `ModelAdmin`.

That way you can change the widgets of the fields in question:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.fields['your_field'].widget.attrs.update({'data-hello': 'world'})
        return form
```

Comment: but what if I want a dynamic data-attribute. like in dropdow list item in admin? thanks